# Import or load ".dat" format file in matlab (if matrix size is 1000x1000) & loaded variable should also be in matrix format

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load a data file '.dat' format in matlab script.

```
A=[1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890]
C= importdata('A.dat')
```

but its not working. 
result matrix after import arrange all the values in only two columns.

how i load a 1000x1000 matix in the code script?

Comment: I check all the old discussion formats which are relevant to my question but no format worked

Comment: The file extension by itself doesn't give us much info.  "dat format" isn't a single thing. You have to know how the data is arranged in the file (including if there are header lines, etc).